# Certificado ssl inválido ao acessar por navegadores de celulares

Tags: amazon-aws, ssl, openssl

Configurei os certificados ssl no servidor Ec2 do amazon para os sites da empresa onde trabalho e no desktop ficou perfeito. Mas quando acesso pelo celular o https fica vermelho e o navegador informa que o certificado é inválido. Esse problema não ocorre em desktop. Alguém já passou por algo parecido e saiba me informar o motivo disso ocorrer?

No chrome por exemplo aparece:

SUA CONEXÃO NÃO É PARTICULAR
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: São certificados pagos ou autoassinados?

Comment: Pagos e não venceu o prazo de renovação. Não entendi porque no desktop não da problema só no celular. rapidssl.

Comment: Após diversas pesquisas, constatei que o certificado comprado e assinado pela entidade certificadora Rapdssl não é compatível com dispositivos móveis. **O próprio Rapdssl informa e vende somente a GeoTrust com licença de uso do mesmo certificado digital para ilimitados servidores sem custo adicional e compatível com dispositivos móveis**. Ou seja, eu tenho que trocar o certificado atual para ser assinado pela GeoTrust. Somente assim terá o reconhecimento válido em dispositivos móveis.